# Is there a way to get 'named' cells using EPPlus?

Tags: epplus, epplus-4

I have an Excel file that I am populating programmatically with EPPlus.

I have tried the following:

```
// provides access to named ranges, does not appear to work with single cells
worksheet.Names["namedCell1"].Value = "abc123";

// provides access to cells by address
worksheet.Cells["namedCell1"].Value = "abc123";
```

The following does work - so I know I am at least close.

```
worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "abc123";
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, its a bit misleading.  The Named Ranges are stored at the `workBOOK` level and not the `workSHEET` level.  So if you do something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Get_Named_Range_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494913/is-there-a-way-to-get-named-cells-using-epplus

    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\NamedRange.xlsx");
    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var wb = pck.Workbook; //Not workSHEET
        var namedCell1 = wb.Names["namedCell1"];

        Console.WriteLine("{{\"before\": {0}}}", namedCell1.Value);
        namedCell1.Value = "abc123";
        Console.WriteLine("{{\"after\": {0}}}", namedCell1.Value);
    }
}
```

You get this in the output (using an excel file with dummy data in it):

```
{"before": Range1 B2}
{"after": abc123}
```

Comment: I think this is not misleading because named ranges are common to all workbook (they must be unique per workbook)

Comment: @DanieleArmanasco actually in Excel 2013, in the _Create Named Cell_ dialog box you have the option to choose to scope the name either at WorkBook or at WorkSheet level.