# Excel 2010 named range collection is empty

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, epplus

I have created an excel file (excel 2010) and set some cell names.
I would like to get this name in my code with epplus lib.
Worksheet has a special property for it *Names* but this collection is empty  all the time.

```
var currentCell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];

var name = worksheet.Names.SingleOrDefault(e => e.FullAddressAbsolute == currentCell.FullAddressAbsolute);
```

I just wonder is it issue in excel, or i need use other way to get it.

Comment: Are the names you defined in excel scoped as "workbook", or as "worksheet" ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking in the wrong collection.  Typical named ranges are actually saved in the workBOOK and not the workSHEET.  See this answer:

[Is there a way to get 'named' cells using EPPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494913/is-there-a-way-to-get-named-cells-using-epplus/30517104#30517104)